# WP Term Images with no posts in category

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have used the following plugin, [WP Term Images](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-term-images/), to set images for each category and it works... but only when the category has at least one post.

```
<?php // image id is stored as term meta
$categories = get_the_category();
$category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
$image_id = get_term_meta( $category_id, 'image', true );
// image data stored in array, second argument is which image size to retrieve
$image_data = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $image_id, 'large' );
// image url is the first item in the array (aka 0)
$image = $image_data[0];
if ( ! empty( $image ) ) {echo  $image;}; ?>
```

However when a category has no posts inside of it the following error is returned even though the category has an image attachment

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in [..]/theme/archive.php on line 14

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in [..]/theme/archive.php on line 14
```

Comment: You may try to take a look into the `$categories` and `$image_data` variables and check if they are arrays that contain elements.

Comment: Try this: var_dump($categories);

Comment: check whether the $categories variable contains any data or not, i think there is no data in that variable as there is no post assigned to it, therefore, it is not receiving that category value.

Comment: @PrateekVerma I cant figure out how make it work... any help?

From the var_dump I get:  array(0) { }